# Font style in math mode

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols, amsmath

How can I generate this font style in Math mode? See attachment for font. [image]

Comment: Have you tried on Detexify?

Comment: Thanks. I have gotten it.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's the `pxtx` fraktur font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frak=pxtx]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\(\mathfrak{R}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. That is it,  an R. This one is good enough. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

What about the below?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

$\Re$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need `amssymb` for `\Re`.  It's built in.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks, will take care in future...Shall I update now?

Answer (score 2):

Is this close enough?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{R}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is close but not enough. The R should not point. Thanks though.